# Multi-threading between JAVA and MATLAB function instances by several instances of TCP socket connection

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab

Is there any way to achieve multithread java function instance with multithread Matlab function instance that could connect and synchronize each other? I found that Matlab is a single thread. I explored a lot and cound n't find any solution/idea.

Is there any existing solution that can create multithread TCP socket connection (several instances as per need) between Java and Matlab, where Matlab uses a client socket and Java uses a server socket?

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: The question is quite broad; what are you trying to parallelize exactly?

Comment: The second part, where I established a TCP connection between Java (server socket) and Matlab (client socket). I want to retrieve multiple instances of data from Matlab to Java. Since in the connection, a port is manually assigned, I cannot change it for every other instance, instead it should support multi-threading for the same.